# $ \mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}, \dots , \{n\})$ showing $\cup_{n\geq0} \mathcal{F}_n $ is not a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification, borel-sets, algebras

**Problem :** We consider on $\mathbb{N}$, for all $n\geq 0$ the sigma algebra $ \mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}, \dots , \{n\})$ show that the sequence of sigmas  $(\mathcal{F}_n, n\geq 0)$ is increasing but $\cup_{n\geq0} \mathcal{F}_n $ is not a sigma algebra.

**Solution :** 
Let $ \mathcal{F} = \cup_{n\geq0} \mathcal{F}_n $
suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra, we have :

$\{2n\} \in \mathcal{F}_{2n} \subset \mathcal{F} $ and $2\mathbb{N}=\cup_{n\geq0} \{2n\}$

This way, there exists $n_0$ such that $2\mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{F}_{2n}$. But the only elements of infinite cardinal of $\mathcal{F}_{n_0}$ are of the form $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$ , where $A$ is a subset of $\{0,1,\dots,n_0\}$ we obtain a contradiction.

**End of solution**

What I thought of doing first was trying to verify the three axioms of a sigma algebra, using a result of the lecture that a union sigma algebras is not a sigma algebra,

But I don't understand the way this solution is constructed,

- why are we supposing $\mathcal{F}_{2n}$ a subsequence of a sigma algebra is not necessarily a sigma algebra, Is there some result I have missed?
- **there exists $n_0$** such that $2\mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{F}_{2n}$ , why there exist? if $\mathcal{F}_{2n}$ is a sigma algebra, $\Omega = 2\mathbb{N}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_{2n}$
- **"But the only elements of infinite cardinal of $\mathcal{F}_{n_0}$ are of the form $\mathbb{N} \setminus A$"** , I spent an hour looking for what this means I don't get it, did I miss another result here?
- How did we use this fact : "$(\mathcal{F}_n, n\geq 0)$ is increasing **but** ..." I mean how does it contradict anything? I am guessing it is either trying to use the monotone class theorem "the Dynkin system" which I don't see how it relates to this problem, or I have missed some result ...

Comment: A different approach: $\mathcal F$ contains all singletons. If it is a sigma algebra then it must contain all subsets. But Each $\mathcal F_n$ is countable and so is their union.

Comment: I don't think I get the idea of this approach, countably infinite unions of countable sets is countable, but $\mathcal{F}$ containing all signletons is infinite, we should have a contradiction to prove it is not stable by countable unions? But we should not have a contradiction because $\mathcal{F}$  containing all singletons is still countably infinite?

Comment: Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2236778/4280), which seems a repeat.

Comment: right thank you

Comment: @Khan The  power set of $\mathbb N$ is not countable, but $\mathbb F$ is countable.

Comment: Ah, yes thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite countable Union of $\sigma-\text{Algebras}$ exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236778/infinite-countable-union-of-sigma-textalgebras-exercise)

Comment: Well, for me , it is indeed pretty related, it gives a version of the solution which I have presented in my question, but It either doesn't answer what I don't get about the particular proof I presented and the way it's written, or I don't get it, I am contenting with elaborating what I know on the idea of alternative approach Kavi Rama Murthy has written, and letting the particular details of my question for later

Comment: $\mathcal F$ can be recognized as the collection of subsets of $\mathbb N$ that are finite *or* cofinite. Then $\sigma(\mathcal F)=\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ because $\mathbb N$ is countable and $\mathcal F$ contains all singletons. Then $\sigma(\mathcal F)$ also contains sets that are not finite *and* are not cofinite (e.g. $2\mathbb N$). So $\sigma(\mathcal F)\neq\mathcal F$ which means exactly that $\mathcal F$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.